# Geometrically unirational varieties that are not unirational

Tags: rational-points, birational-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry

By a *variety* over a field $k$, I mean a scheme that is separated and
of finite type over $k$. I indicate changes of the base ring by
subscripts.

> Does there exist a smooth and projective variety $V$ over some field $k$, with
> $V(k)\neq\emptyset$, that is *geometrically unirational*, i.e.,
> there exists a dominant rational map $$\mathbf{P}^n_{\overline{k}}
> \dashrightarrow V_{\overline{k}}$$ for some integer $n$, but not
> unirational, i.e., there does **not** exist a dominant rational map
> $$\mathbf{P}^n_k \dashrightarrow V$$ for any integer $n$.

I don't recall ever coming across an example of a $V$ as in the question. It is a classical fact that any such $V$ has to have dimension at least $2$. Furthermore, I think I would have known if any examples existed where the dimension of $V$ is $2$. On the other hand, while the condition $V(k)\neq\emptyset$ is
certainly needed to keep the question from having a trivial answer in
the positive (e.g., let $V$ be a smooth cubic surface in
$\mathbf{P}^3_k$ that does not have a $k$-point), it seems too
unnatural to me to be sufficient for a negative answer to the
question in general.

NB. I realize that some people (including myself at times) use the
term "(uni)rational" for the concept I'm referring to as "geometrically
(uni)rational". However, when comparing the two properties, I somehow
prefer talking about "geometrically unirational vs. unirational" to
"unirational vs. unirational over the ground field".

**Some edits made** to reflect comments by Jason Starr and ayanta; see below.

Comment: To prevent trivial examples, you should at least add "normal" to your list of hypotheses on $V$, but it is probably best to add the hypothesis "smooth".

Comment: (deleted previous comment expressing my lack of understanding) I see what you mean now. Thanks!

Comment: For an easier example than smooth cubic surfaces, consider a conic without a rational point.

Comment: Your "classical fact" is false! For $k_0$ of characteristic $p > 0$, let $k = k_0(t)$ and `$V:=\{y^q=x-tx^p\}$` for a $p$-power $q > 2$.  This is a smooth irreducible $k$-subgroup of $\mathbf{G}_a^2$ with closure in $\mathbf{P}^2_k$ that is regular (but *not $k$-smooth*). Thus, $V_{\overline{k}} \simeq \mathbf{G}_a$. But $V$ is not unirational over $k$ since $V(k)$ is finite and hence not Zariski-dense in $k$: if $p > 2$ then `$V(k) = \{(0,0)\}$`, whereas if $p=2$ then `$V(k)=\{(0,0),(1/t,0)\}$` since $q > 2$ (for $q=2$ it is a smooth affine conic with a $k$-point, so rational!).

Comment: @ayanta: Your type of example is why I suggested the OP add "smooth" to the hypotheses on $V$.

Comment: It seems to be open in dimension 2. In the article http://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.6798v1.pdf written two months ago we can read "With this assumption, it is not known if geometrically rational surfaces [...] are unirational over their field of definition."

Comment: @Jeremy:  I am pretty sure that there are counterexamples coming from equivariant compactifications of $\textbf{PGL}_{r^2}$-torsors whose generalized Severi-Brauer scheme modeled on $\textbf{Grass}(r,r^2)$ has a rational point (these torsors must have index $r$).  I will try to write up an example.  These examples would have pretty large dimension (I guess $4^2-1 = 15$ is the minimum possible).

Comment: @Jason: My example is smooth.  It is only the projective compactification that is merely regular: non-smooth at one point.  But $V$ itself is smooth, and the question didn't say that $V$ is meant to be complete. So I guess that is a hypothesis which the OP meant to say but omitted.

Comment: ayanta: you are absolutely right. I guess I should insist on smooth as well as projective. This is the case of which I was thinking anyway; however, while typing the question I didn't see a problem with omitting these hypotheses. Clearly I didn't think hard enough. The "classical fact" I was trying to get away with is that if $V$ is a geometrically unirational curve over any field $k$, it is actually rational; and if $V$ moreover has a $k$-point, then it is isomorphic to $\mathbf{P}^1_k$. Of course, this is only true when I require $V$ to be smooth and projective. 

Comment: A question: If a geometrically unirational variety has a rational point, does one know whether its rational points are already Zariski dense?

Comment: I for one don't know. The next logical question would be the one where "$V(k) \neq \emptyset$" is replaced by "$V(k)$ is Zariski-dense".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of a counterexample, but I will need to add more details.  Let $k$ be an infinite field.  Let $G$ be a (smooth, connected) semisimple algebraic group scheme of adjoint type over $k$.  Assume that $G$ is "quasi-split", i.e., there exists a closed smooth subgroup scheme $B$ in $G$ that is smooth over $k$ and whose base change to an algebraic closure of $k$ is a maximal, connected, solvable subgroup scheme.  Let $\mathcal{T}_B$ be a $B$-torsor over $k$ whose associated $G$-torsor, $\mathcal{T}_G$, is nontrivial.  Obviously I need to prove that there exists such a $(G,B,\mathcal{T}_B)$, but let's assume for the moment that it exists.

There is a "wonderful compactification" $\widehat{G}$ defined over $k$ that contains a copy of $G$ as a dense open subscheme and such that the natural action of $G\times G$ on $G$ (by left and right multiplication) extends to all of $\widehat{G}$.  The scheme $\widehat{G}$ is smooth and projective over $k$.  The minimal $G\times G$-orbit in $\widehat{G}$ is isomorphic to $(G/B)\times (G/B)$.  Using the left action on $\mathcal{T}_G$ and the right action on $\widehat{G}$, form an action of $G$ on $\widehat{G}\times \mathcal{T}_G$.  Since the action of $G$ on $\mathcal{T}_G$ is free, so is the action on $\widehat{G}\times \mathcal{T}_G$.

The  geometric quotient $\widehat{\mathcal{T}_G} = (\widehat{G}\times \mathcal{T}_G)/G$ is a smooth, projective $k$-scheme that contains $\mathcal{T}_G$ as an open subscheme and is geometrically isomorphic to $\widehat{G}$.  The stratum $(G/B)\times (G/B)$ becomes $(G/B)\times (\mathcal{T}_G/B)$.  The point is, since $\mathcal{T}_G$ is induced from the $B$-torsor $\mathcal{T}_B$, the quotient $\mathcal{T}_G/B$ has a $k$-point, namely the image of $\mathcal{T}_B$.  Thus, the "deepest stratum" in $\widehat{\mathcal{T}_G}$ has a $k$-rational point.  Yet, since $\mathcal{T}_G$ is nontrivial, there are no $k$-rational points in this dense open subset.  Over an infinite field $k$, this is enough to insure that $\widehat{\mathcal{T}_G}$ is not unirational.  However, it is geometrically isomorphic to $\widehat{G}$, which is rational.

$\textbf{Edit}$.  The "details" above turn out to be impossible in the adjoint case, as Xuhan points out: there is no such triple $(G,B,\mathcal{T}_B)$.  In the intermediate case, it may be possible.  However, even for perfect fields (where there is no issue with constructing wonderful compactifications via descent), the wonderful compactification of a non-adjoint group tends to be singular (although geometrically normal).

Comment: @Jason: is there a literature reference for the wonderful compactification over a general (infinite) field? All references I have seen assume the field to be algebraically closed. Also, to have a nontrivial $B$-torsor over $k$ we cannot take $G$ to be either simply connected or adjoint, since in such cases ${\rm{H}}^1(k,B)=1$ (as the maximal $k$-tori of $B$ are "induced", and hence have vanishing ${\rm{H}}^1$, in these two extreme cases).  So what sort of $G$ do you plan to try?

Comment: @Jason: In char. 0 singularities are fine since a resolution cannot have $k$-points if the original variety doesn't. Also, $G(k)\rightarrow(G/P)(k)$ is surjective for any connected reductive $k$-group $G$ and parabolic $k$-subgroup $P$ over any $k$, so ${\rm{H}}^1(k,P)\rightarrow{\rm{H}}^1(k,G)$ has trivial kernel. Hence, any nontrivial $B$-torsor over $k$ does the job in char. 0. If $\tilde{G}$ is the quasi-split simply connected central cover and $\tilde{T}$ a maximal $k$-torus in a Borel, it suffices to find a $k$-subgroup $\mu\subset Z_{\tilde{G}}$ so ${\rm{H}}^1(k,\tilde{T}/\mu)\ne 1$.  

Comment: @xuhan:  Regarding singularities, unfortunately the argument above only produces a $k$-point on the singular variety, not on the resolution.  It might be possible to use the "stacky" description of the wonderful compactification ala Martens-Thaddeus (who realize the singular variety as the coarse moduli space of a smooth stack) to produce $k$-points that lift to a resolution.

Comment: @Jason: Oops, I got myself confused for what is needed with $k$-points, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Rosenlicht found forms of $\mathbb{G}_a$ over a nonperfect field $k$ that have only finitely many points, hence are not unirational over $k$ (but, of course, become rational over the algebraic closure of $k$).

Comment: The question was revised to require $V$ to be projective and smooth, precisely to avoid such examples (noted in the comments to the question by ayanta).